# How do I use the contain function in AWS Athena to find certain text

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a simple table let's say Names. In the column First I want to find all rows that contain the letters Jo. It would then result in Joe and John.

However when I try and use contains function it talks about an array and I have no idea how to get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

[`CONTAINS()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/filtering-arrays.html) is a function that checks if an elements is in an array.

You can use the `LIKE` operator (which is Standard SQL).  If you want names that start with "Jo":

```
where name like 'Jo%'
```

If you want to match names with "Jo" anywhere:

```
where name like '%Jo%'
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the `like` before but got zero records. I did it iwht the % % and it worked. Thank you so much!